# Multiple inheritance design issue in iOS

Tags: ios, oop, design-patterns

I have below classes

```
@interface Document : NSObject
//Root document
@end

@interface ExtendedDocument1 : Document
//sublcass of document, with specific behaviour
@end

@interface ExtendedDocument2 : Document
 //sublcass of document, with specific behaviour
@end

@interface EncryptedDocument : Document
//Supports encryption of document
@end
```

If I want to encrypt the ExtendedDocument(1/2), how can I achived this? If I subclass the ExtendedDocument with EncryptedDocument, the extended document will become encrypted by default.

How to solve this design issue? which pattern I can use to solve this kind of problems. Looks like I am missing something.

Comment: Why not make Document something you _can_ encrypt but don't have to? That way, ExtendedDocument1/2 _can_ encrypt but they don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could receive an intermediary interface reference in the EncryptedDocument initializer. To do so, you must find out which is the minimally sufficient interface between all your class interfaces needed to expose information for documents to be encrypted. It may so happen that Document does the job. If not, you should create this interface and extend all others from it, or create a protocol, and make your classes implement it. Then, just add a specialized initializer for EncryptedDocument:

```
@interface EncryptedDocument
- (id)initWith:(Document*)document;
// whatever else an encrypted document has to expose in its interface ...
@end
```

This has the advantage of keeping the original plain document untouched, and if you don't need it anymore you can release it for garbage collection.

But in this case you might want to separate the responsibility of actually implementing the encryption, which is the job of an algorithm implementation, from the EncryptedDocument representation, which is more tied to the data model of such a document. One way to achieve that is to employ the Strategy Design pattern and remove the encryption work from the EncryptedDocument. Perhaps you could remove the EncryptedDocument altogether from the hierarchy, changing the return value for the *encrypt* method bellow. But this depends more on your data model and application domain. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

```
@interface DocumentCypher
- (id)initWithMethod:(id<CypherMethod>)method;
- (EncryptedDocument*)encrypt:(Document*)plainText;
@end;
```

But this depends on the complexity of the problem you are trying to tackle, the more "naive" and simple solution could be easily refactored when the need for introducing more complex behavior arises.

Comment: Based on @dpereira answer I think its better to have a DocumentCypher object and that should present inside the Document object to handle encryption

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that inheritance is not the swiss army knife of programming. In that specific case, a protocol such as Encryptable can help support an interface implementation and call an instance of an object by referring to the protocol type. Check the following link:

[Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

Comment: Thanks... i just figured out, inheritance is not the right approach. protocol i a am not sure.. because it is not multiple inheritance problem(title of the question is not right)

Comment: Then check @dpereira's answer which is adding an extra abstraction by essentially passing a protocol (aka interface) to the Document's class constructor and later on calling this functor (encryptDocument) to do some sort of encryption (or any other transformation) of your data model (or not).